# How are the keys defined in pymysql if we use DictCursor?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I was looking for a way to better represent the output we get after running a query on a MySQL table via pymysql and stumbled upon `DictCursor`.
I gave it a shot and was able to achieve the following

```
import pymysql

# Connect to mysql database
conn = pymysql.connect('db_conn_str', 'user_r',
                       'pwd_r', 'db_name')

# Run a query to list all tables in database
cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute('show tables')
tables = cur.fetchall()

# We get a list of dictionaries
print(tables)
```

I get an output as follows

```
[
    {'Tables_in_db_name': 'table_x'}, 
    {'Tables_in_db_name': 'table_y'}, 
    {'Tables_in_db_name': 'table_z'}
]
```

I was wondering if the key `Tables_in_db_name` is something we can define ourselves? If not how are the name of the keys picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key comes from the header of the result set.

You can't change the header if you run the command `SHOW TABLES`. Here's an example of this command in the mysql client:

```
mysql> show tables from test;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| bar            |
| foo            |
+----------------+
```

If you want more control, you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (which is exactly what `SHOW TABLES` actually does internally):

```
mysql> select table_name as `my_custom_key` from information_schema.tables 
  where table_schema='test';
+---------------+
| my_custom_key |
+---------------+
| bar           |
| foo           |
+---------------+
```